# Javascript Canvas: base64 back to file after resizing&resampling?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert Data URI to File then append to FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata)

Is it possible to save rendered canvas back to a file in Google Chrome?

I have tried this:

```
canvas.getAsFile('foo.jpg','image/jpeg')
```

Doesn't work.

This works only in Firefox:

```
canvas.mozGetAsFile('foo.jpg')
```

Of course I can and probably will just send raw base64 encoded string to server and decode it there.

But if it's possible to do it on client-side, i would prefer doing it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata) Stack Overflow Question and Answer might help you.